# Compilation taking too long when including svg

Tags: compiling, svg

This is a general question. I have been very happy when using `inkscape` for my LaTeX files. Now I am preparing a presentation using `beamer` and I am trying to include `svg` files into my presentation using TeXmaker. I am having two problems. The first is that the compilation takes a long time to complete and the other is that scrolling in the `pdf` file is slow.
If I want to find a replacement to the `svg` files in which format should I save my drawings?

Comment: Can you save them as pdf? That renders quite fast for me in my TeX files. I believe TeXmaker is converting all these `svg` files to pdf everytime you compile the file. The same happens when you use the `eps` format. I might be wrong, so that's why I'm not making this an answer. If this works for you, let me know, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Inkscape can save as `pdf`, so that might be the easiest way to save your images and speed up the process. I recommend converting all text to paths to get the most consistent results.

Comment: How do you include `svg` files into your presentation?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to be fast? I suppose you are creating a pdf or ps file each time you compile it. For debugging, creating just the dvi is generally sufficient; and since the images are not embedded in the dvi, it compiles in no time.

When you believe you are absolutely done, you can create the pdf, which takes some time. Think of the initial debug process as the pre-processing and pdf compilation as the processing.

Comment: `draft` mode does the same without having to reconfigure your TeX IDE to go the good old-fashioned dvi route.